# How do I set "has_title = false" for an existing node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I understand how to set the node attribute 'has title' via the `hook_node_info()` when creating a node programmatically. However, I struggle to edit this attribute for a node that has been created with the built in Drupal node designer. Can anyone please give me advice on how to modify this attribute, for example on a node such as "article"? Which hook do I use and when? Could I even modify this attribute directly in the database and therefore get this changed permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/modules/node/content_types.inc#l298) good comment in source:

```
// title_label is required in core; has_title will always be true, unless a
// module alters the title field.
$type->has_title = ($type->title_label != '');
```

So, you can alter the form and customize it. 
I have created a simple example, because I found it interesting.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 * Alter 'node_type_form'
 */
function nodetitle_off_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $type = $form['#node_type'];
    $default_value = $type->has_title;
    // Create simple flag
    $form['submission']['nodetitle_off'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Has title'),
        '#default_value' => $default_value,
        '#weight' => -1,
    );

    $value = !empty($form_state['input']) ? isset($form_state['input']['nodetitle_off']) : $default_value;
    if (!$value) {
        // Make field not required and empty
        $form['submission']['title_label']['#required'] = FALSE;
        $form_state['values']['title_label'] = '';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, Kalabro. This helps me getting things straight! Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

The [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module could be useful to you.